# How to get MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE of an image in my gallery in android?

Tags: java, android

I have an image here: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1487951012463.jpg
The title is a text obviously. This title is shown in the default gallery viewer in android 5.1.1. (select image-->details)

But from my app, I just cannot read it.

Can someone help me out?
The code I am using is:

```
public static void loadTitle(Context context) {

Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1487951012463.jpg");

String[] projection = new String[] {
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LATITUDE,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.LONGITUDE,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION,
        MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE,
};
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, projection, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();
String title, name;
title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE));
name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));

Log.e("Title", title);
Log.e("Display_Name", name);
```

}

The app crashes as the cursor contains nothing.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.database.Cursor.moveToFirst()' on a null object reference
```

I call this from an Activity if this matters...

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT - EDIT

I have tried to do the same with the ExifInterface as it was suggested. The result I am getting with this is 'null'.

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1487955364408.jpg");

        String x = exif.getAttribute("XPTitle");

        Log.e("Title with Exif: ", "X = "+ x );
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First, `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1487951012463.jpg` is not a `Uri`. It is a path. A `Uri` has a scheme.

Second, even if you put the `file` scheme on that `Uri` (which would make the `Uri` valid), you cannot use that `Uri` with `query()` on `ContentResolver`. `query()` only works with a `content` `Uri`, and you do not have one of those.

Presumably, that title is in an EXIF header in the JPEG file, though I am not certain which EXIF tag is the correct one. If you can find that out, you can use the support library's `ExifInterface` to read in the value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are correct, it is an EXIF in the header. The tag name is 'XPTitle' (if am right). I tried to use the ExifInterface to get that tag but everything I got back was null. I read yesterday somewhere that the ExifInterface is not realiable and it's better to avoid it. That's why I started to go on a different path.

So what you are saying about the Uri is, the way I am trying to convert the path into uri is incorrect, right?

 Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1487951012463.jpg");

Can you please suggest me a workaround way? Many thanks

Comment: contentUri  replace with "MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI"

Comment: @d4Mn: "I read yesterday somewhere that the ExifInterface is not realiable and it's better to avoid it" -- `MediaStore` itself, for the images that indexes, uses an `ExifInterface` implementation to read in the metadata. Third-party apps will either query the `MediaStore` or use an `ExifInterface` implementation themselves.

Comment: @VishalPatolia: That represents a collection of all indexed media.

Comment: @CommonsWare based on your requirement you can display title of MediaStore.IMAGE...Thank u

Comment: I have added the ExifInterface stuff that I was trying before, please have a look.

Comment: @d4Mn: Copy the image from the phone to your development machine, then use some tools to dump all the EXIF headers (e.g., `exif` on Ubuntu) to find the right one.